# jsp need to write a text with different colors

Tags: java, css, jsp, jsf

I need to write in jsf 2 texts on a line with different colors. Here is my code:

```
<h:panelGrid id="accessinfo_grid" columns="3">
<h:outputText id="loginid" value="#{msgs.loginId}" styleClass="label"/>
<h:outputText id="loginid_asterix" value="#{msgs.asterix}" styleClass="error_message"/>
<h:inputText  id="inputusername" disabled="true" value="#{userAccount.userName}"/>
<h:outputText id="password" value="#{msgs.passwordID}" styleClass="label"/>
<h:outputText id="passwordid_asterix" value="#{msgs.asterix}" styleClass="error_message"/>
<h:secretText  id="inputpassword" disabled="true" value="#{userAccount.password}"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

I want the output to be to be something like this with * with red color:

```
Login:* edit_box
Password:* edit_box
```

But now is something like this:

```
Login:   * edit_box
Password:* edit_box
```

I want that * red to be just after the first text. Probably i should try to use something else then a panelGrid but I don't know what/how.

I am newbie at this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `<h:panelGrid>`, which generates a HTML `<table>`, every direct child JSF component will end up in its own `<td>`. You need to group the JSF components which should end up in the same `<td>` in a `<h:panelGroup>`.

```html
<h:panelGrid id="accessinfo_grid" columns="2">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputText id="loginid" value="#{msgs.loginId}" styleClass="label"/>
        <h:outputText id="loginid_asterix" value="#{msgs.asterix}" styleClass="error_message"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:inputText id="inputusername" disabled="true" value="#{userAccount.userName}"/>

    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputText id="password" value="#{msgs.passwordID}" styleClass="label"/>
        <h:outputText id="passwordid_asterix" value="#{msgs.asterix}" styleClass="error_message"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:inputSecret id="inputpassword" disabled="true" value="#{userAccount.password}"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

*(note that I replaced the non-existent `h:secretText` by `h:inputSecret`, not sure why you used it)*

Note that this has **nothing** to do with CSS. You'd still have exactly the same problem when disabling CSS. I'd suggest to take a JSF pause and concentrate on reading some decent HTML tutorial to understand better how it all works what JSF is generating (you can see it by opening the JSF page in browser and doing rightclick and *View Source*).

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, Can you recomand some tutorials? I read something about this but not too much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `<h:outputText>` and add a class attribute through `styleClass="color-red"`. Example:

```
<h:outputText styleClass="color-red" value="*" /> ...
```

Then in your CSS you create the corresponding class:

```
.color-red {
    color: #F00;
}
```

Comment: <h:panelGrid id="accessinfo_grid" columns="2">
<h:outputText id="login_lbl" value="#{msgs.loginId}" styleClass="label"/>
<h:inputText  id="inputusername" disabled="true" value="#{userAccount.userName}"/>
<h:outputText id="currentpassLbl" value="#{msgs.currentpass}" styleClass="label"> </h:outputText>
<h:outputText id="asterixLbl" value="#{msgs.asterix}" styleClass="error_message"> </h:outputText>
<h:inputSecret id="currentpass"  label="#{msgs.currentpass}"   style="width:155px" value="#{userAccount.currentPassword}" required="true" maxlength="20" disabled="#{userAccount.apUser}"/>

Comment: This makes no sense.  Either you use style="color: red" or you use styleClass="highlight" and set the red colour in css.  naming your class 'color-red' has no extra value.  For this, it would also make sense to just add the style 'field-required' to the label, and use css content or background to add the red star.

Comment: Excuse-me for the upper comment. Thanks for reply. You have right but in this styleClass="error_message" I set color to red. Thanks anyway!